# How to focus automatically on the current date in vis.js timeline

Tags: javascript, dom-events, vis.js

I wrote a program that uses vis.js timeline and focuses on the current date on the click of a button:

`<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" onclick="timeline.focus(0)">Focus on current date</button>`

where

`var timeline = new vis.Timeline(container, data, options);`

and

`var data = [
      //create an item in the dataset corresponding to the current date
    {id: 0, content: 'today', start: Date()},...];`

Now I would like the timeline to focus automatically on the current date when the user changes its range. I tried to use the *rangechange* event:

`timeline.on('rangechange', function (properties) {
            timeline.focus(0);
    });`,

but focusing does not occur as expected.

Would you please help me understand what's going on and how I could implement this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*rangechange* gets fired multiple times, every time the timeline changes, so even when the timeline is animating, trying to focus on the specific event it keeps firing the *rangechange* event.
There are a couple of solutions to your problem.

1. You could check the *byUser* property of the *properties* object and only trigger the focus when it is true (the user zoomed or scrolled in the timeline), to prevent it from jumping around erratically. Simply replace your current event listener with

   ```
   timeline.on('rangechange', function(properties) {
       if (properties.byUser) {
           timeline.focus(0);
       }
   });
   ```
2. Simply use the *rangechanged* event, which only gets fired once for each timeline change. If you plan to have range changes that are not user driven this is the event you should use. Again, the change is simple and you only need to change the event listener to

   ```
   timeline.on('rangechanged', function(properties) {
       timeline.focus(0);
   });
   ```